# Can I query solr for documents in two locations with matching field values?

Tags: java, solr, geolocation

I have some documents in solr with username and location fields on them.

I can query for all documents in location:[x,y TO x,y] OR location:[x,y TO x,y] and page them, 10 at a time.

But can I query for all documents in those two locations where the username on the document also appears on a document in the other location?

e.g. Show me all documents for users that have created documents in England and Japan.

Or am I going to have to figure out how to query this in a service tier in front of it and figure out how to page the results there?

Edit: I suppose I'm asking for a union of two queries based on a given field, maybe, ish, not quite?